# Звездный рейтинг с шрифтом "Fontello"

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('body').on('mousemove', '.blockElem', function(e) {
    var x = e.offsetX==undefined?e.layerX:e.offsetX;

if(x >= 1 && x < 20) {
    $('.elem1').html('&#10031;');
  $('.elem2').html('&#10027;');
  $('.elem3').html('&#10027;');
  $('.elem4').html('&#10027;');
  $('.elem5').html('&#10027;');
  var result = 1;
}

if(x >= 21 && x < 40) {
    $('.elem1').html('&#10031;');
  $('.elem2').html('&#10031;');
  $('.elem3').html('&#10027;');
  $('.elem4').html('&#10027;');
  $('.elem5').html('&#10027;');
  var result = 2;
}

if(x >= 41 && x < 60) {
    $('.elem1').html('&#10031;');
  $('.elem2').html('&#10031;');
  $('.elem3').html('&#10031;');
  $('.elem4').html('&#10027;');
  $('.elem5').html('&#10027;');
  var result = 3;
}

if(x >= 61 && x < 80) {
    $('.elem1').html('&#10031;');
  $('.elem2').html('&#10031;');
  $('.elem3').html('&#10031;');
  $('.elem4').html('&#10031;');
  $('.elem5').html('&#10027;');
  var result = 4;
}

if(x >= 81 && x < 100) {
    $('.elem1').html('&#10031;');
  $('.elem2').html('&#10031;');
  $('.elem3').html('&#10031;');
  $('.elem4').html('&#10031;');
  $('.elem5').html('&#10031;');
  var result = 5;
}

$('.result').html(result);});$('body').on('mouseleave', '.blockElem', function() {
$('.result').html('OUT');});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yfp09xt2/ - Набросал рейтинг с `html` символами

https://test.xn--80akhmlofgv.net/new_Real_Estate/test - с шрифтом **"Fontello"**

При использовании **"Fontello"** `mouseleave` не срабатывает. Помогите разобраться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Звездочки закрывают общий блок от *нормального* события `mouseleave`. Поскольку вы их все равно не используйте (их события), просто отключите их от взаимодействия с мышью:

```
.starRating span {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

меняйте class а не html

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').on('mousemove', '#starRating', function(e) {
    var x = e.offsetX == undefined ? e.layerX : e.offsetX;

    var dataOldRating = $('#starRating').data('oldRating');
    if (dataOldRating === 'no') {
      var oldRating = $('#starRating').html();
      $('#starRating').data('oldRating', oldRating);
    }
    var rating = 0;

    if (x >= 1 && x < 11) {
      $('.starRating1 i').attr('class', "icon-star-half-alt");
      $('.starRating2 i').attr('class', "icon-star-empty-1");
      $('.starRating3 i').attr('class', "icon-star-empty-1");
      $('.starRating4 i').attr('class', "icon-star-empty-1");
      $('.starRating5 i').attr('class', "icon-star-empty-1");
      rating = 0.5;
    }

    if (x >= 11 && x < 23) {
      $('.starRating1 i').attr('class', "icon-star-3");
      $('.starRating2 i').attr('class', "icon-star-empty-1");
      $('.starRating3 i').attr('class', "icon-star-empty-1");
      $('.starRating4 i').attr('class', "icon-star-empty-1");
      $('.starRating5 i').attr('class', "icon-star-empty-1");
      rating = 1;
    }

    if (x >= 23 && x < 34) {
      $('.starRating1 i').attr('class', "icon-star-3");
      $('.starRating2 i').attr('class', "icon-star-half-alt");
      $('.starRating3 i').attr('class', "icon-star-empty-1");
      $('.starRating4 i').attr('class', "icon-star-empty-1");
      $('.starRating5 i').attr('class', "icon-star-empty-1");
      rating = 1.5;
    }

    if (x >= 34 && x < 45) {
      $('.starRating1 i').attr('class', "icon-star-3");
      $('.starRating2 i').attr('class', "icon-star-3");
      $('.starRating3 i').attr('class', "icon-star-empty-1");
      $('.starRating4 i').attr('class', "icon-star-empty-1");
      $('.starRating5 i').attr('class', "icon-star-empty-1");
      rating = 2;
    }

    if (x >= 45 && x < 56) {
      $('.starRating1 i').attr('class', "icon-star-3");
      $('.starRating2 i').attr('class', "icon-star-3");
      $('.starRating3 i').attr('class', "icon-star-half-alt");
      $('.starRating4 i').attr('class', "icon-star-empty-1");
      $('.starRating5 i').attr('class', "icon-star-empty-1");
      rating = 2.5;
    }

    if (x >= 56 && x < 67) {
      $('.starRating1 i').attr('class', "icon-star-3");
      $('.starRating2 i').attr('class', "icon-star-3");
      $('.starRating3 i').attr('class', "icon-star-3");
      $('.starRating4 i').attr('class', "icon-star-empty-1");
      $('.starRating5 i').attr('class', "icon-star-empty-1");
      rating = 3;
    }

    if (x >= 67 && x < 78) {
      $('.starRating1 i').attr('class', "icon-star-3");
      $('.starRating2 i').attr('class', "icon-star-3");
      $('.starRating3 i').attr('class', "icon-star-3");
      $('.starRating4 i').attr('class', "icon-star-half-alt");
      $('.starRating5 i').attr('class', "icon-star-empty-1");
      rating = 3.5;
    }

    if (x >= 78 && x < 89) {
      $('.starRating1 i').attr('class', "icon-star-3");
      $('.starRating2 i').attr('class', "icon-star-3");
      $('.starRating3 i').attr('class', "icon-star-3");
      $('.starRating4 i').attr('class', "icon-star-3");
      $('.starRating5 i').attr('class', "icon-star-empty-1");
      rating = 4;
    }

    if (x >= 89 && x < 100) {
      $('.starRating1 i').attr('class', "icon-star-3");
      $('.starRating2 i').attr('class', "icon-star-3");
      $('.starRating3 i').attr('class', "icon-star-3");
      $('.starRating4 i').attr('class', "icon-star-3");
      $('.starRating5 i').attr('class', "icon-star-half-alt");
      rating = 4.5;
    }

    if (x >= 100 && x <= 112) {
      $('.starRating1 i').attr('class', "icon-star-3");
      $('.starRating2 i').attr('class', "icon-star-3");
      $('.starRating3 i').attr('class', "icon-star-3");
      $('.starRating4 i').attr('class', "icon-star-3");
      $('.starRating5 i').attr('class', "icon-star-3");
      rating = 5;
    }

    $('#ColRating').html(rating);
  });


  $('body').on('mouseleave', '#starRating', function(e) {
    //var oldRating = $('#starRating').data('oldRating');
    //$('#starRating').html(oldRating);
    $('#ColRating').html("OUT");
  });
});
```